# PostgreSQL Backup from pg_dumpall (Ubuntu)

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, restore, pg-dumpall

I was tasked with writing a python script to backup our current instance of Alfresco ECM. The backup works like a charm. I am running into problems with restoring PostgreSQL from the text dump .sql file.

Here is my command:

```
psql -f /home/alfresco/alfresco-backup/20180124/20180124_183146.sql -h 
localhost
```

Here is the response:

```
psql: FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist
```

I can not find any information on this online. I have looked deeply into Postgres documentation and found nothing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are not specifying database name in command and its defaulting to postgres for database name. You can use pg_dump to backup database. Here is how you run a pg_dump command.

```
pg_dump -U db_user -W -F t db_name > /path/to/your/file/dump_name.tar
```

Comment: This is true in the context of dropping a single database, however for this assignment I was instructed to use pg_dumpall. pg_dumpall has a different restore command than pg_dump.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `postgres` and the `template1` databases have been deleted. That shouldn't happen.

Use `initdb` to create a new, healthy DB cluster.